# Statistical Learning book with theoretical content

Tags: machine-learning, references

I'm currently reading the book 'An Introduction to Statistical Learning with application in R(ISLR)', it is very helpful for learning the applications of statistical model, but less complement of theoreotical content or mathematical proof/derivation of formulas. I'm often confused with some conclusion/formulas provided in that book without theoretical explanation. Does anyone can give me some resources or books that emphasizes on theoretical aspect of statistical learning? Or other statistical learning book with theoretical problems is OK as well.

Comment: Thanks，I will read the books suggested in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try elements of statistical learning. It is freely available [here](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf). It has quite a bit of theoretical content, but not many proofs. Most of the derivations and/or proofs are published in separate papers by Hastie and Tibshirani.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion，where can I find the papers？

Comment: Many of them are on Stanford University's library [website](https://library.stanford.edu/). Unfortunately for some of them you will need to have an account. If you are a student or researcher, this should not be too hard to acquire. Otherwise, most of them you should also be able to find on Google scholar. 
On Stanford's website you will also find lots of class notes and presentations which often explains the theory very well :)

Answer (score 0):

Two excellent books that also give you theoretical background in stat. learning are:

https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642201912

https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/highdimensional-statistics/8A91ECEEC38F46DAB53E9FF8757C7A4E

Also, I would recommend another van de Geer book:

https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319327730

All are excellent books to get you started on the topic from theory stand point. Hope this helps.

Comment: wow，many thanks，I will read these books.

Comment: no problem. I thought of another (award-winning) book,
https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/highdimensional-probability/797C466DA29743D2C8213493BD2D2102
which basically provides background for concentration inequalities heavily used in high-dimensional stats. This can be a useful addition after you get familiar with other books.